# Vector values to diagonal of matrix using python

Tags: python

How do I get values from a vector to be the values of the diagonal in a matrix? I'm using python.

Comment: first of all, is there anything you have tried then show a dummy example of a vector and matrix, so that we don't have to imagine stuff,, and if possible give a expected output

Comment: As the answers show, you can do quick and dirty python matrix examples with lists. But for anything more serious, you should use the numpy library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list comprehension that will do it:

```
[[v[i] if i==j else 0 for i in range(len(v))] for j in range(len(v))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like:

```
vec = [1,2,3,4]
->
mat = [[1,0,0,0],
       [0,2,0,0],
       [0,0,3,0],
       [0,0,0,4]]
```

then the general idea is to loops through vec with a counter and append [0,0,0,0] to mat after making the i'th element of that list vec[i].

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of lists to make a matrix eg:

```
values = [1,2,3]
matrix =[[1 0 0]
         [0 2 0]
         [0 0 3]]
```

Then the following code should work

```
values = [1,2,3]
matrix=[]
size = len(values)
for i in range(size):
  tmp = []
  for j in range(size):
    if i == j:
      tmp.append(values[i])
    else:
      tmp.append(0)
  matrix.append(tmp)
print(matrix)
```